# How to properly test a method in a class that calls a method from the same class with Junit and Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am fairly new to Unit testing.

I have a class with a few methods, and in one of them we call the result from one of the other methods from the same class, should we mock, or we should only mock while using methods from collaborators like other classes?

*Code:*

```java
class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

  UserReader reader = new UserReader("/path");
  AccountChecker check;

  public boolean userExists(String userName) {
    List<User> users = mappedUsers();
    for (User u : users) {
      if (u.getName().equals(userName)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public List<User> mappedUsers() {
    List<String> userList = reader.readUsers();
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String u : userList) {
      userList.add(new User(u));
    }
    return userList;
  }

}
```

So the question is if I want to test the method `userExists()`, should I simply test the method without any mocks or try to mock the `mappedUsers()` method while testing the `userExists()` method?

Comment: You should mock ```readUsers()``` in order to test both ```userExists()``` and ```mappedUsers()```

Comment: Depends on the number and size of your methods. If you call multiple methods you could end up in a lot of preparation in your tests. If you are only interested in testing method 1, you also need to mock the things that happen in the methods called by that method.